# cursores: 1. Obtener el libro, con el precio más caro

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE DATABASE Crisol
Go

USE  Crisol
Go

CREATE TABLE LIBRO(CODLIB VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,      
                   TITULOLIB CHAR(32),      
                   AUTORLIB  CHAR(24),      
                   EDITOLIB  CHAR(13),      
                   AREALIB   CHAR(9),       
                   PRECIOLIB NUMERIC(8,2),  
                   NHOJASLIB INT,           
                   ANOLIB    INT)
go

CREATE TABLE TRABAJADOR 
                       (COD_TRA VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                        AP_TRA VARCHAR(15) NULL,
                        AM_TRA VARCHAR(15) NULL,
                        NOM_TRA VARCHAR(15) NULL,
                        FECHA_NA SMALLDATETIME NULL,
                        SUELDO DECIMAL(8,2) NULL,
                        GENERO_TRA CHAR NULL,
                        AREA_TRA VARCHAR(30) NULL)

GO

INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES ('00001','DE LA MADRID','GUTIERREZ' , 'MARICIELO', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'01/11/1980'),980,'F','CONTABILIDAD')
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES ('00002','HURTADO','CORONEL', 'NILDA', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'10/10/1976'),980,'F','CONTABILIDAD')
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES ('00003','PAREDES','MARTINEZ','EDITH', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'10/10/1976'),1500,'F','SISTEMAS')
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES ('00004','CARDOSO','VALLADARES','HENRY', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'10/10/1980'),1200,'M','SISTEMAS')
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES('00005','UBILLUS','MARQUEZ','MIGUEL ANGEL', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'05/01/1976'),980,'M','CONTABILIDAD')
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES('00006','LIZARRAGA','DEL OLMO','NUPCIA MASSIEL', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'05/10/1980'),1300,'F','SISTEMAS')
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES('00007','AGUIRRE','RIVADENEIRA','VANNIA', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'05/10/1975'),1200,'F','SISTEMAS')
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES('00008','JUAREZ','LAZO','GINO', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'05/10/1969'),1200,'M','LOGISTICA')
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES('00009','PINTADO','ROBLES','JUAN ABEL', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'08/28/1984'),1000,'M','LOGISTICA')
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES('00010','BARRANTES','MEDINA','LUIS ALBERTO',CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,'08/28/1975'),1000,'M','LOGISTICA')
GO

INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1000','VISUAL FOX','RUBEN IGLESIAS','RAMA','LPROG',60,489,1997)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1001','POWER BUILDER 6.','RAMIRO HOOL','UNI','LPROG',80,410,1999)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1002','ANALISIS Y DISEÑO DE SIST.','KENDALL & KENDALL','PRINTICE HALL','ANALISIS',100,913,1997)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1003','POWER BUILDER 6.','WILLIAM B. HEYS','QUE','LPROG',150,843,1999)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1004','VISUAL BASIC','CESAR BUSTAMANTE','GRAPPERU','LPROG',35,390,1997)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1005','VISUAL FOX PRO','LES & JHON PINTER','MC GRAWHILL','LPROG',25,567,1997)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1006','GUIA C++','JULIO VASQUEZ PARAGULLAS','UPSMP','LPROG',50,780,1997)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1007','MS C++','BECK ZARATIAN','MICROSOFT','LPROG',80,600,1999)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1008','VISUAL FOX PRO 6.00','CESAR BUSTAMANTE','UNI','LPROG',35,450,1999)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1009','AUTOCAD 2000','J.A. TAJADURA J. LOPEZ','MC GRAW HILL','CAD',40,480,1998)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1010','EFECTOS COREL','ANOMINO','MACRO','ARTE',50,400,1998)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1011','EL VENDEDOR MAS GRANDE DEL MUNDO','OG MANDINO','DIANA','LIDERAZGO',15,121,1968)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1012','EL PODER DEL CARISMA','MIGUEL ANGEL CORNEJO','ESTRELLA','LIDERAZGO',15,123,1992)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1013','7 HABITOS DE LA GENTE EFECTIVA','STEPHEN  R. COVER','PAIDOS','LIDERAZGO',50,460,1989)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1014','CRITERIOS EVA. PROY.','NASSIR SAPAG CHAIN','MC GRAW HILL','PROYECTOS',10,144,1997)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1015','COMO DIRIGIR MICRO EMP.','VICTOR ABAD G.','IPEDE','PROYECTOS',10,110,1995)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1016','LA MAGIA DE PENSAR EN GRANDE','DAVID JASEPH SCHWRTZ','HERREROS MEX','LIDERAZGO',10,258,1960)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1017','SQL SERVER VB','WILLIAM R. VAUGHN','MICROSOFT','LPROG',60,1000,1999)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1018','VISUAL FOX 6.00','MENACHEN BAZIAN','QUE','LPROG',55,1000,1999)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1019','INTELIGENCIA EMOCIONAL','DANIEL GOLEMAN','ZETA','LIDERAZGO',48,396,1996)
INSERT INTO LIBRO VALUES('1020','LA TERCERA OLA','ALVIN TOFFLER','MC GRAW HILL','LIDERAZGO',50,250,1998)
go

SELECT * FROM LIBRO
SELECT * FROM TRABAJADOR
Go
```

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor edita tu pregunta agregando más información, revisa[ask], saludos.

Comment: Aqui no hacemos deberes, para que tu pregunta no termine cerrada debes añadir las pruebas que hayas hecho y no simplemente el codigo necesario para que te hagan los deberes.

Comment: Cursores 1: Los cursores **NO** se usan para obtener el valor más alto.

Answer (score 1):

**Consultar el líbro más caro:**

si tu tabla es esta:

```
LIBRO(CODLIB VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,      
                   TITULOLIB CHAR(32),      
                   AUTORLIB  CHAR(24),      
                   EDITOLIB  CHAR(13),      
                   AREALIB   CHAR(9),       
                   PRECIOLIB NUMERIC(8,2),  
                   NHOJASLIB INT,           
                   ANOLIB    INT)
```

mira que fàcil és. Iremos pas o paso.

Selecciona la tabla que te interesa

```
SELECT *
FROM LIBRO
```

Lo queremos ordenar por el valor de la columna "precioLib"

```
SELECT *
FROM LIBRO
ORDER BY PRECIOLIB
```

El problema es que esto nos ordenara de menor a mayor, así que hay que ordenarlo al revés (descendentemente).

```
SELECT *
FROM LIBRO
ORDER BY PRECIOLIB DESC
```

El problema de esto es que nos da toda la tabla, y solo queremos uno, ¿no? el más caro. Pues le decimos que nos de solo el primer resultado.

```
SELECT *
FROM LIBRO
ORDER BY PRECIOLIB DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**En SQL Server** sería con TOP en vez de LIMIT

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM LIBRO
ORDER BY PRECIOLIB DESC
```

Comment: Limit no es usable en Sql Server, que por supuesto si usan otros motores, pero en la pregunta han puesto la etiqueta `SQL Server`. La ejecución dará: `Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'LIMIT'.`. La implementación de la funcionalidad en el caso de TSQL es con el operador [TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Editado! Gracias. NO me fijé en la etiqueta.